# Flutter: Multiline TextField (TextFormField) simply won't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new at Flutter so I might have gotten things wrong but ... I can't get my head around this issue.
I have ready many posts on how allow multi-line text for `TextField` / `TextFormField`.

I have tried setting `maxLines` to `null` or to a big number, to enforce max lines (or not), but nothing works !

How come something as simple won't work ?

```
// in a Scaffold of a StatefulWidget
 body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child:      TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          minLines: 1,
          maxLines: 5,
        ),
```

I have tried on two different real Android devices and hitting the `ENTER` key does nothing. Unfortunately, I can't test the behavior on iOS as I don't have a Mac.

---

**EDIT 1**
Following solution offered by **copsonroad**, the following code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              widget.event.shortName == null || widget.event.shortName.isEmpty
                  ? AppLocalizations.of(context).eventEditorTitleNewEvent
                  : AppLocalizations.of(context)
                      .eventEditorTitleEditEvent(widget.event.shortName)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            if (_canSave == true) ...[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                onPressed: () => _saveEventAndPop(),
              )
            ],
          ]),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 5 * 50.0,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter a message"),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Produce the following result:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 3):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var maxLines = 5;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: maxLines * 50.0,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter a message"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: maxLines,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Testing it on Android:

[image]

Comment: OK I am gonna try and copy / paste your solution and see what I get. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It does not work .... I am going to edit my answer to show you the result. You will notice that hitting `ENTER` actually does something: it trims the text !

Comment: I tested it on Android also, it works, please check the updated screenshot.

Comment: OK it works on the emulator but only with soft keyboard (but not with my computer's keyboard though). Why would it not work on my Samsung S9 and OnePlus 6T ?

Comment: I think you should file a bug in that case.

Comment: It's possible. I am also using latest stable version: `1.12.13+hotfix.8` what is yours ? Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: OK so I got it working. But something is strange. Indeed, when I first set up my work environment, Android Studio downloaded actually the Flutter SDK from the beta channel and not the stable channel. But in my `pubsec.yaml`, I declared using version `1.12.13+hotfix.8` which does not exist in the beta channel ! Why the difference ? How I can build using a beta SDK when configuring the project on a stable SDK ? Anyway it works. Maybe I should file the bug... thanks for your help, answer validated :)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a bug with `TextInputType.multiline`. It simply doesn't work with some custom keyboards (i.e. SwiftKey). There is [an issue in flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74041#issuecomment-916696069) where I described my workaround.

First of all, I've wrapped my `TextFormField` with `RawKeyboardListener` like this:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        autofocus: false,
        onKey: (rawKeyEvent) {
          final isFormSkippedEnterEvent = rawKeyEvent is RawKeyDownEvent &&
              rawKeyEvent.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter);

          final needToInsertNewLine = isFormSkippedEnterEvent &&
              keyboardType == TextInputType.multiline;
          if (needToInsertNewLine) {
            TextEditingControllerHelper.insertText(controller, '\n');
          }
        },
        child: TextFormField(...)
...
```

When Gboard is used, RawKeyboardListener doesn't receive Enter event at all, it's sent directly to the text field. But when using for example SwiftKey, instead of inserting new line to the text, RawKeyboardListener receives an event `RawKeyDownEvent#a5131(logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#70028(keyId: "0x100070028", keyLabel: "Enter", debugName: "Enter")`. I check if I need to insert a new line (no need for this if `TextFormField` is configured to be single line) and access `TextEditingController` to alter user's input. All the magic happens inside `TextEditingControllerHelper.insertText()`:

```
class TextEditingControllerHelper {
  static insertText(TextEditingController controller, String textToInsert) {
    final selection = controller.selection;
    final cursorPosition = selection.base.offset;
    if (cursorPosition < 0) {
      controller.text += textToInsert;
      return;
    }

    final text = controller.text;
    final newText =
        text.replaceRange(selection.start, selection.end, textToInsert);
    controller.value = controller.value.copyWith(
      text: newText,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: selection.baseOffset + textToInsert.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I do is check cursor/ selection position. In case of an empty field I just attach a newLine (this helper can work with other inputs, i.e. emojis) and exit. Otherwise I insert a new line on place of existing selection (if there is no selection, text is just inserted where cursor is placed) and move cursor to be after the inserted text. Works fine in my tests (Pixel 3a with Gboard/SwiftKey, Galaxy S8 with Samsung keyboard, iPhone simulator).